# How to install a Swig enabled Python extension (QuickFix)

Tags: python, windows, installation, quickfix

[QuickFix](http://www.quickfixengine.org/) includes bindings for Python. How do I install QuickFix so that I can `import quickfix` in Python on Windows?

- `easy_install quickfix` doesn't work
- both binary and source [downloads](http://www.quickfixengine.org/download.html) don't include `setup.py`
- The source download has the following folder called python (amongst many others) - how do I use it?

[image]

Even less promising is the binary download which has a `.lib` file and an include folder with all the header files.

Please don't assume knowledge about makefiles or swig :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#quickfix

Comment: I'm marking this as the right answer as it solved my problem, but if someone will post a description of how this could be done manually I'll transfer the answer as it would be a better fit for the question

Comment: A repository completely awesome! Thank you very much, cgohlke. And @Jonathan for asking exactly what the most of us think. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any Windows project files, and SWIG implies that there is some native (i.e. C/C++) code to be compiled. Odds are fairly good that this simply won't work under Windows, although you may try Cygwin if it's really important to get this working.

Comment: This is just a sub-directory called python which is part of the entire project which has a visual studio solution and much more. I showed only this as I thought this would be the key

Comment: So... my mind reading abilities aren't yet fully developed. Got it.